# Questions about the existence of 5d & 6d version of 4d ${\cal N}=2$ SCFTs

Tags: quantum-field-theory, supersymmetry, conformal-field-theory, spacetime-dimensions

Given a **4d N=2 Superconfomal field theory (SCFT)** with a **global flavor symmetry** ( **$\mathfrak{f}$** as the corresponding lie algebra), can we clam that this theory can always flow from a **5d ${\cal N}=1$ UV SCFT on $S^{1}$** with **the same flavor symmetry algebra** $\mathfrak{f}$, or even **6d ${\cal N}=(1,0)$ SCFT on $T^{2}$** with **the same flavor symmetry algebra** $\mathfrak{f}$?

Thanks for any answers or suggestions on references!

Comment: Hi @Yongchao Lv. Consider adding references and links in order to receive useful and focused answers.